# Why there is an accuracy drop on the test dataset (around 7% drop) after loading the saved model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am building a model for classifying whether the person in the image is wearing a mask or not. I used EfficientNetB0 model with custom data augmentation (sequential) layer all stacked with the help of Functional layer. After I saved the model (in h5 format) and loaded the saved model, the accuracy on the test dataset was different.

The accuracy on the test dataset originally was around 98%
After loading the saved model, the accuracy on the test dataset plummeted to 91%

I used `image_dataset_from_directory` to load the images for train, test and validation sets.

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir, image_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode="rgb", batch_size=64, label_mode="categorical"
)
```

Then created a prefetch dataset

```
train_dataset = train_data.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

This is the custom data augmentation layer:

```
data_aug = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.3),
    keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.3)
])
```

The model

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = data_aug(inputs)
x = eff_model(x, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"], 
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

history = model.fit(train_dataset, steps_per_epoch=len(train_dataset), epochs=20,
                    validation_data=val_dataset, validation_steps=len(val_dataset))
```

This is the accuracy my model achieved originally on the test dataset.

[image]

Saving the model and reloading the saved model:

```
model.save("face_Detect.h5")
load_model = keras.models.load_model("/content/face_Detect.h5")
```

This is the accuracy achieved on the loaded model:

[image]

I have no idea because the accuracy on the test dataset for the original model and loaded model should be similar but this is a huge difference. Is this a bug in Tensorflow 2.7.0 or am I making some horrendous mistake ?

Comment: This might be of some help: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875

Comment: the paths to model.save and load_model are different (one is absolute, the other relative). make sure they are the same, so you aren't dealing with different files.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data.

Comment: This is obvious that when we shuffle the data while training the model. Don’t shuffle the data if you expect your model to  behave before and after save and load model. Thanks!